# Problem with cnn extract feature the use svm image classifiaction

Tags: conv-neural-network, svm, feature-extraction, image-classification

I wanna use vgg16 to get features and label for SVM image classification.
I get the following error

```
y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (14630, 3) instead.
```

this is my code for extract features and label

```
def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,3))
    generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(directory,target_size=(224, 224),batch_size = batch_size, class_mode='categorical')
    i = 0
    print('Entering for loop...')

    
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = model.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 14630)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, 1500)
train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (14630, 7 * 7 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (1500, 7 * 7 * 512))

param_grid = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
]
svm_model = svm.SVC()

clf = GridSearchCV(svm_model, param_grid, cv=5)
clf.fit(train_features, train_labels) #error here for train_labels
best_model = clf.best_estimator_
print(clf.best_params_)
y_pred = best_model.predict(validation_features)
print('accuracy', accuracy_score(validation_labels, y_pred))
```

The shape of train_labels is (14630,3), and train_features is (14630,25088) **7 * 7 * 512=25088**
how can I reshape the label and feature for svm.fit(x,y)
I think that should be an easy question, but I got stuck.

Comment: I put my SVM code here, and when I put train_label into fit, then I got error y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (14630, 3) instead. @matt

Comment: when I reshape train_label (43890,), but it still cannot fit cause train_feature is (14630,25088), and have another error Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14630, 43890]

Comment: I use # add error in my code. i think that output should be (14630, ) but I don't know how to do it. @matt

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing yet. You generate some image data. You run it through a 'model.predict' and you use that output as "features". Then you return both labels, and features. Both of which are outputs of the *other* model.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what do u mean. clf.fit(x,y),the x should be feature, y is label right

Comment: i want use feature and label from vgg to be input for svm fit. do u know how to reshape (14630,3)to (14630,)

Comment: No, x should be the input and y should be the output. Feature and Label are both common terms for an output.

Comment: What does extract features return? You load some image data, input and output. You store the output as labels. Then you use **another** model to create features. What do you want your VGG to do with this information? What is "features" we just know it is the output of another model.

Comment: I am a little confused now

Comment: If you can clarify a few things it might help. On this line, `inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:` what are `inputs_batch` and `labels_batch`?